# I want a function that changes the 2 numbers of an array quicksort

Tags: c++, arrays, declaration

im working on a small programm which is using a quicksort algorithm.
Unfortunaly my swap function is not working.
I just wanna swap array[i] with array[j] but it says a and b are not declared.

```
void swap(int data[a], data[b]) {

      int temp = data[a];
      data[a] = data[b];
      data[b] = temp;


      return data[a], data[b];
}
```

Comment: what is `a` and `b`? They are not declared in your code....

Comment: No need to program this. There is already a [`std::swap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) function available in the STL.

Comment: Welcome to C++. It's time to start using Standard Library containers like `std::vector<int> x` instead of C-style arrays like `int x[y]`. It's also time to pass things in by reference if you intend to modify them. Depending on pointer decay is really not the best way to tackle this.

Comment: You're returning a non-void value from a void function?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems in your code...

First, you want to swap the values of two integers (in an array), hence the function is working on `int`s. Further you want to modify the parameters, hence you should use references (no pointers, because passing a null pointer makes no sense for a `swap`).

Next, you have a `return` statement in a function that is declared to return nothing (`void` return type). Also, this

```
return data[a], data[b];
```

Wrong data types and function declared as `void` aside, is not doing what you expect. The comma operator evalutes both operands and the result is the operand on the right side. Anyhow this doesnt really matter here, because you don't have to return anything (instead the parameters are modified).

Fixing those we have:

```
void swap(int& a,int& b) {    
      int temp = a;
      a = b;
      b = temp;
}
```

However, you really should not write this code. There is [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) in `<utility>`, that already does what you want.

**PS**: Passing c-style arrays to functions is a completely different story. You do not need to pass an array to the function to modify only two elements of it. Anyhow, you should probably use `std::vector` as it is much easier to work with.